# Removing of tail items in F#

Tags: .net, f#, f#-interactive

I am a beginner in the F# world. I have a question regarding the removal of items in a list.
Suppose you have a arbitrary list, lets say

```
let list1 = [0;1;2;0;3;4;0;0]
```

I want to remove all the last zeroes, so that the list becomes

`list1 = [0;1;2;0;3;4]`

I've tried by reversing the list, and checking if the head was zero and then make a recursive call to the tail

```
let rec remove ps = if List.rev(ps).Head <> 0 then ps else remove(ps.Tail);;
```

However I either end up with an error code of an empty list or it just returns the original list.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your 'bug' is this. First, you reverse the list, so:

```ml
[0;0;4;3;0;2;1;0]
```

You then check if it starts with `0` - it does. You then pass the tail *of the original list*. So you removed the first number, not the last:

```
[1;2;0;3;4;0;0]
```

As you never remove the last zero, it will return `true` when testing for `0` until you end up calling `remove` with an empty list. You then throw an exception trying to get the `Head` of an empty list.

This fixes the bug, recursively calling with the tail of the reversed list (so without the last number), reversed again to the original order:

```ml
let rec remove ps =
    let reversed = List.rev ps
    if reversed.Head <> 0 then ps else remove (List.rev reversed.Tail)
```

Using pattern matching may be a little more idiomatic. This also won't throw with an empty list:

```ml
let rec remove list =
    match List.rev list with
    | 0::xs -> remove (List.rev xs)
    | _ -> list
```

You could also do the same thing without recursion. Reverse the list once, skip until the value is not `0`, then reverse it again:

```ml
let remove list =
    list
    |> List.rev
    |> List.skipWhile (fun x -> x = 0)
    |> List.rev
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and thank you for an explanation rather than just pure code.